# How to use Spring Kafka's Acknowledgement.acknowledge() method for manual commit

Tags: java, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka first time and I am not able to use Acknowledgement.acknowledge() method for manual commit in my consumer code as mentioned here https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#committing-offsets. Mine is spring-boot application. If I am not using manual commit process than my code is working fine. But when I use 
Acknowledgement.acknowledge() for manual commit it shows error related to bean. Also If I am not using manual commit properly please suggest me the right way to do it.

Error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field ack in Receiver required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment' in your configuration.
```

I googled this error I found that I need to add @Component but that is already there in my consumer code.

My consumer code looks like this: Receiver.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Receiver {

    @Autowired
    public Acknowledgment ack;

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.TestTopic}")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord){
            System.out.println(consumerRecord.value());
            latch.countDown();
            ack.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

My producer code looks like this: Sender.java

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Sender {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Map<String, Object>> kafkaTemplate;

    public void send(Map<String, Object> map){
            kafkaTemplate.send("TestTopic", map);

    }

}
```

**EDIT 1:**

My new consumer code looks like this: Receiver.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Receiver {

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.TestTopic}", containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment ack){
            System.out.println(consumerRecord.value());
            latch.countDown();
            ack.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

I changed my configuration class also:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class ReceiverConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String consumerGroupId;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() throws SendGridException {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupId);
            return props;

    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(){
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    /*@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }*/

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Receiver receiver() {
        return new Receiver();
    }
}
```

After adding containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory" to my receive() method I am getting the below error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method kafkaListenerContainerFactory in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'kafkaConsumerFactory' in 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'consumerFactory'


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 24):

For those still looking for a solution to these errors concerning manual acknowledgment, you don't need to specify containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory", instead you can just add:

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
```

to your receiver config just before you return the factory object.

Then you also need:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
```

in consumer config props.

So in the end your listener method can simply look like:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.topic}")
    private void listen(@Payload String payload, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        //Whatever code you want to do with the payload
        acknowledgement.acknowledge(); //or even pass the acknowledgment to a different method and acknowledge even later
    }
```

Comment: Does anyone have a minimal working example of an entire working app using this pattern?

Comment: Sure thing, I created this simple project for you, take a look at my git page:

https://github.com/zim8662/kafka-example

Just run the zookeeper and kafka server locally, or if it's remote change the property in application.properties (along with group and topic properties of course) and try localhost:8080/test in your browser.

Comment: Hi Zim - wondering what happens if you then set `props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true)`? Will kafka still autocommit? and will Spring try to commit again?

Comment: @alex I think this is a simple yet good explanation on this property:
https://medium.com/@danieljameskay/understanding-the-enable-auto-commit-kafka-consumer-property-12fa0ade7b65

Comment: I think your answer is not good, since the change will affect all Kafka listeners bounded to the ListenerContainerFactory.

Comment: When we are dealing acknowledgement manually, we need to set the ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE and map.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,false) . Otherwise we will end up the below exception.
org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0 in public void com.demo.test.analytics.testanalytics.consumer.FLReservationKafkaConsumer.consumeReservation(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String): 1 error(s): [Error in object 'payload': codes[];arguments[];

Comment: auto commit is disabled by default now (spring kafka listeners).  so its really just setting that ackMode.  What im trying to figure out is the Acknowledgment piece because it seems NOT needed.  it seems you can throw kafka exceptions to control behavior of offset commit.

Answer (score 17):

You really should follow [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafka-listener-annotation):

> When using manual `AckMode`, the listener can also be provided with the `Acknowledgment`; this example also shows how to use a different container factory.

```
@KafkaListener(id = "baz", topics = "myTopic",
          containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(String data, Acknowledgment ack) {
    ...
    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

There is really nowhere noted that `Acknowledgment` is a bean. So, change your `receive()` `@KafkaListener` method signature appropriately and remove that `@Autowired` for suspicious  `Acknowledgment` bean - it just doesn't exists because this object is a part (header) of each received message.

Comment: Hi @Artem , I did the changes but now getting another bean error. I update my question with new Edit. The spring kafka documentation is not that much clear.

Comment: 1. You still don't have `Acknowledgment` arg in your `receive()` method. So, I'm not sure what is that `ack` var for. 2. You have some mix of raw Spring Kafka configuration and Spring Boot. You should consider to start from there: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-kafka and just reconfigure out-of-the-box `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean via proper `ConsumerFactory` bean. In your case it is `ConsumerFactory<String, String>`, but has to be `ConsumerFactory<?, ?>`

Comment: Saying "you should follow the docs" is unproductive; the docs here are wildly confusing and not beginner friendly. A link to a minimal working application would be nice.

Comment: @ArtemBilan
The documentation link is broken.

Answer (score 9):

Those who are using spring boot application, simple add below to your application.yml (or environment specific file).

```
spring:
  kafka:
    listener:
      ack-mode: manual
```

Above change will make `Acknowledgment ack` argument available inside
`receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment ack)` method automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Java code:

```
@Service
public class ServiceCallKafkaListener {

    @KafkaListener(id = "listenerId",
            groupId = "groupListenerId",
            topics = "topicName")
    public void listenServiceCall(@Payload String message,
                                  Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        //here is your logic for message processing
        boolean logicForMessageProcessingCompleted = true;
        if (logicForMessageProcessingCompleted) {
            //manual commit
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        }
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
#type of acknowledgment mode
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=MANUAL_IMMEDIATE

#property that turns off auto commit
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
```